# Googlebot following some 301 that doesn't exist for root domain

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, hreflang

We have locale versions of our site `www.example.com` (UK), `us.example.com` (USA), `fr.example.com` (France) etc.
In Google webmaster tools I have configured each of these domains with their country and we also have the `hreflang` tags implement.

My problem is that if I visit `www.example.com` it loads fine, but when I fetch as bot (As Google) or even when I type the URL into services such as slack, it pulls the meta data for our US site, but clicking on the link doesn't redirect you?

I assume this is nginx doing the 301? I am worried that this will be cached on Google for eternity?

Comment: When Googlebot gets a redirect that users don't, it is sometimes a sign of a hacked site.   One thing to check is if your site has been hacked: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/

Comment: Google never caches anything for eternity.   Googlebot always comes back to re-crawl URLs.   Even URLs with permanent status such as "301 Permanent Redirect" and "410 Gone" get re-crawled.   It may take 2 to 6 weeks for a recrawl, depending on how prominent it is.

Comment: Can you share the URL?  It is hard to guess the problem without doing some testing against it.